# How to set a variable for an external HTML template in Go?

Tags: go, go-templates, go-gin, go-html-template

I've two Go templates.

`top.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ .title }}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
```

and `register.html`:

```
{{ template "top.html" . }}
    <h1>Register account</h1>
...
```

Currently to set the title I use the function:

```
r.GET("/register", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "register.html", gin.H{
        "title" : "Register Account"
    })
})
```

This is not ideal as I have to set the parameter for every webpage. How can I set the `title` in `top.html` from `register.html`? I'd much rather have something that looks like:

```
{{ set .title = "Register Account" }}
{{ template "top.html" . }}
    <h1>Register account</h1>
...
```

Of course, the above code does not work. Is there anything available to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by implementing a template function. For example:

```
func mapset(m map[string]string, key, val string) error {
    m[key] = val
    return nil
}
```

Then, after registering it with the [`Funcs`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs) method, instead of `{{ set .title = "Register Account" }}` you would use it as:

```
{{ (mapset . "title" "Register Account") }}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/a08OVDpLLH4